# Hardhat and foundry, contract bytecode different

Tags: solidity, hardhat, bytecode, foundry

I'm developing a contract in hardhat project. But now I want to write test by foundry. My problem is I'm using `create2`, but when running contract by hardhat and foundry they gave different addresses. I found the reason is the `bytecode` of contract from hardhat and foundry are different (10 ~ 20 bytes close the end). Here is my hardhat config + foundry toml.

hardhat.config.js

```
 config = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.18",
    evmVersion: "london",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
      },
    },
  },
...
}
```

foundry.toml

```
evm_version = 'london'
optimizer = true
optimizer_runs = 200
solc_version = '0.8.18'
via_ir = false
```

This is how they different, they have the same length, but different near the end
[image]
What reasons affect to bytecode?

Comment: This might be because of what bytecode are you trying to fetch. Maybe one of them outputs the creation code and another one simply runtime bytecode?

Comment: I get log both compiled bytecode and runtime bytecode. The compiled and runtime bytecode are the same for each foundry(in out) and hardhat(in artifacts).

Comment: I just updated the question, add image about how they r different.

Comment: I'll amplify the issue. I am unaware of this behavior. 

I guess this issue on Git Hub is by you, I'll amplify this issue in my connections. https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/5559

Comment: Yes, that issue is mine

Comment: The issue can be solved by here:https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/5559#issuecomment-1673454231